# Both audio channels play only out of left earphone on front jack

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones, headphone-jack

So I have a very strange problem I'm stumped with. I've got a pair of headphones for my computer. When I plug it into the jacks on the back of the motherboard, everything's fine and dandy. But I've also got a pair of speakers that are much more convenient to be plugged in there, and the headphones at the front.

But when I plug the headphones into the front jacks, sound only comes out of one headphone. Namely, the left one. No matter how I change the balance in Realtek Manager, it sounds the same. When I test the sound, it turns out I hear both audio channels at the left headphone. But if I plug the jack just right almost halfway out, I get sound on both headphones, albeit somewhat muted down. But when I plug in the headphones from my phone into the front jack, everything's fine. Normally I'd conclude there's something wrong with the headset, but it works perfectly fine if I plug it into the rear jacks.

Does anyone know what the issue here is and how to take care of it? I'm running Windows 10, and yes, I do have the latest drivers for my mobo.

Thanks for you time in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the jack is not reaching far enough into the hole. Maybe the connector in the computer case is pushed back a little.

Comment: do these headphones have a microphone? what about the "phone headphones?" Are there 3 segments (two dark rings) on the connector or 4 (with 3 dark rings)?